# c# append new items to list item

Tags: c#, list

The code below has a list with two rows in it, I want to be able to amalgamate the two lines and sum the income field based on the Country.

```
public class City
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Country {get;set;}
 public double income {get;set;}
}
public class myClass
{
void Main()
{

 var c = GetCities();
 var d = c.GroupBy(s => new {s.Country, s.Flag, s.Name}).Select(s => new City { Country = s.Key.Country, Flag = s.Key.Flag, Name = s.Key.Name});
 d.Dump(); //LINQPAD output to screen
}

public List<City> GetCities()
{
 List<City> cities = new List<City>();
 cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Istanbul", income= 22.00, Country = "Turkey"  });
 cities.Add(new City() { Name = "", income= 44.88, Country = "Turkey" });
 return cities;
}
}
```

in my real application the list is being generated in two places, but the data needs to show on one single line.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what is actually wrong. Could you clarify a bit, perhaps with input data and expected output?

Comment: When i dont do the for loop it comes out all on the one line from the two separate calls.

Comment: The output is not related to the code shown, so you'll need to show how this is being output as well.

Comment: i have shown the output as it would be seen on screen.

Comment: I have made a simpler revision of what i am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my answer

```
var result = c.GroupBy(x => x.Country)
.Select(g => {
var item = g.First();
return new{
Country = item.Country,
Name = item.Name,
income = g.Sum(x => x.income) };
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Well that seem to take the first name and ignore the rest of the names. Then sum the results. Shouldn't your result ignore the name?  Same thing you have without "Name = item.Name." bit???